# run cmd command as administrator through java program

Tags: java

I need to build a java program to reset network in windows 10, this command needs cmd to be opened as administrator I tried to build it, but it gives me this error

```
Cannot run program "runas /profile /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState"": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

this is my code

```
try {
            String[] command
                    = {
                        "runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState\"",};
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
            PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.println("netsh winsock reset");
            stdin.close();
            int returnCode = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);

            stat_lbl.setText("Network reset Successfully");

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I don't understand what the problem is and how can I resolve it

Comment: @ControlAltDel unless that's the only thing this program should do, that's terrible advice. That means running Java with more rights that it needs.

Comment: I tried to run java as administrator but also it gave me error again

Comment: Does that command actually work simply run at the command line without Java?

Comment: yes, this error is resolved as @RobSpoor said but now it require administrator password

Comment: Interesting. I'd no idea you could run a dll without ... rundll ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the command as an array with a single element, which is treated as a single command. You're already giving the command as an array - split it accordingly, where `runas` is the command, and everything else is an argument to `runas`:

```java
String[] command = {
        "runas",
        "/profile",
        "/user:Administrator",
        "cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState",
};
```

Note that you don't have to add quotes to the last argument.

You can make your program a bit better by using `ProcessBuilder`. Now you're redirecting streams yourself, but you can easily let `ProcessBuilder` handle that for you:

```java
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().start();
PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
stdin.println("netsh winsock reset");
stdin.close();
int returnCode = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);
```

Comment: yes, I understand that and that is great answer, I tried it now and it doesn't give me error, but it requires a password

Comment: how can I Enter this password ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I'm guessing using `stdin.println("mypassword")` - before sending `netsh winsock reset` to the process. After all, it's input for the process.